# NextJS Firebase onRequest Function Rewrites

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, next.js

I am working on a project using the Vercel Next.js firebase-with-hosting template found [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-firebase-hosting).

The template uses a Firebase Function to allow for Firebase Hosting. I am trying to add additional Firebase onRequest functions so that I can send request to the server.

I've added the `printTest` function and set the rewrites in the firebase.json file but keep getting 404 errors. I've successfully implemented this before with Express and without NextJS. I think I have an issue with my rewrites.

I've also tested `onCallable`, and `pubSub` functions and these worked great. My guess is I have a rewrite issue. Any help with understanding why this does now work would be greatly appreciated.

```js
const { join } = require('path'); // From NextJS Vercel Base Build
const { default: next } = require('next'); // From NextJS Vercel Base Build
const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'; // From NextJS Vercel Base Build
const nextjsDistDir = join('src', require('./src/next.config.js').distDir); // From NextJS Vercel Base Build
const admin = require('firebase-admin'); // Firebase Admin SDK for NodeJS.
const functions = require('firebase-functions'); // For NextJS + Firebase Functions + Firebase Hosting.
const serviceAccount = require('./firebaesAdminServiceAccountKey.json'); // Service account key for Firebase Admin SDK.
    
// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ Firebase Admin Initialization ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
});
    
// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ Firebase Firestore Initialization ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    
const dba = admin.firestore();
    
// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ Nextjs Configuration ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    
const nextjsServer = next({
    dev: isDev,
    conf: {
        distDir: nextjsDistDir,
    },
});
    
const nextjsHandle = nextjsServer.getRequestHandler();
    
// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ Cloud Functions ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    
// Nextjs Cloud Function to allow for Firebase Hosting.
exports.nextjsFunc = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    return nextjsServer.prepare().then(() => nextjsHandle(req, res));
});
    
exports.printTest = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    console.log('THIS WORKS!');
    res.status(200).send();
});
```

Here is the firebase.json file with the rewrite.

```json
{
    "hosting": {
        "public": "public",
        "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
        "rewrites": [
          {
            "source": "**",
            "function": "nextjsFunc"
          },
          {
            "source": "/printTest",
            "function": "printTest"
          }
        ]
    },
    "functions": {
        "source": ".",
        "predeploy": [
          "npm --prefix \"$PROJECT_DIR\" install",
          "npm --prefix \"$PROJECT_DIR\" run build"
        ],
        "runtime": "nodejs10"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The URL pattern `**` means that all of your requests are sent to `nextjsFunc()` and that includes **/printTest**. Since that is the first rewrite config rule, anything below is ignored.

From the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites), here's an important note:

> Hosting applies the rewrite defined by the *first* rule with a URL pattern that matches the requested path. So, **you need to deliberately order the rules** within the rewrites attribute.

Fix the issue by changing the order and putting the least-strict rule at the end:

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "/printTest",
    "function": "printTest"
  },
  {
    "source": "**",
    "function": "nextjsFunc"
  }  
]
```